# tensorflow object-detection api eval on custom dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have a custom dataset that I trained using tensorflow object-detection api [Faster RCNN].

I saved the model checkpoints. Now, I want to run this model on my eval set. But, I cannot find the script that I use to run on eval set. 
I have tfrecord files for eval set.

How do I run the eval script from the object-detection api for my own saved model checkpoint? I couldn't find the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking fot the [eval.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/legacy/eval.py).

Run this script with the command:

```
python eval.py \
--logtostderr \
--pipeline_config_path=PATH_TO_YOUR_CONFIG_FILE \
--checkpoint_dir=PATH_TO_CHECKPOINT \
--eval_dir=OUTPUT_PATH
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I’ll try this